# Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?

Tags: c++, opengl, recursion, glsl, raytracing

I am writing a GPU-based real-time raytracing renderer using a GLSL compute shader. So far, it works really well, but I have stumbled into a seemingly unsolvable problem when it comes to having both reflections and refractions simultaneously.

My logic tells me that in order to have reflections and refractions on an object, such as glass, the ray would have to split into two, one ray reflects off the surface, and the other refracts through the surface. The ultimate colours of these rays would then be combined based on some function and ultimately used as the colour of the pixel the ray originated from. The problem I have is that I can't split the rays in shader code, as I would have to use recursion to do so. From my understanding, functions in a shader cannot be recursive because all GLSL functions are like inline functions in C++ due to compatibility issues with older GPU hardware.

Is it possible to simulate or fake recursion in shader code, or can I even achieve reflection and refraction simultaneously without using recursion at all? I can't see how it can happen without recursion, but I might be wrong.

Comment: I suppose you're using a Monte Carlo technique - then pick reflection or refraction randomly.

Comment: I think you could try iteration instead. Make a list of rays to process and just add to the list ... for limited recursion layer like 7 rays you could hard code this into static arrays. Another option would be use geometry shader for this and emit new rays in there but I do not know if that is doable as I do not know the architecture of how you are passing data.

Comment: I added **[edit1]** with updated code. So the proof of concept works. However using more that 4th level of recursion with 32 bit floats is sluggish but still a magnitude faster than CPU ray tracers.

Comment: GLSL doesn't allow recursive functions, but it's sometimes possible to eliminate recursion using [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization.

Answer (score 10):

I manage to convert  **back-raytracing** to iterative process suitable for **GLSL** with the method suggested in my comment. It is far from optimized and I do not have all the physical stuff implemented (no Snell's law etc ...) yet but as a proof of concept it works already. I do all the stuff in fragment shader and **CPU** side code just send the `uniforms` constants and scene in form of **32 bit non-clamped float texture** `GL_LUMINANCE32F_ARB` The rendering is just single `QUAD` covering whole screen.

1. **passing the scene**

I decided to store the scene in texture so each ray/fragment has direct access to whole scene. The texture is **2D** but it is used as linear list of 32 bit floats. I decided this format:

```
    enum _fac_type_enum
        {
        _fac_triangles=0,   // r,g,b,a, n, triangle count, { x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 }
        _fac_spheres,       // r,g,b,a, n, sphere count,   { x,y,z,r }
        };
    const GLfloat _n_glass=1.561;
    const GLfloat _n_vacuum=1.0;
    GLfloat data[]=
        {
    //    r,  g,  b,  a,       n,          type,count
        0.2,0.3,0.5,0.5,_n_glass,_fac_triangles,    4,      // tetrahedron
    //        px,  py,  pz,  r,  g,  b
            -0.5,-0.5,+1.0,
             0.0,+0.5,+1.0,
            +0.5,-0.5,+1.0,
    
             0.0, 0.0,+0.5,
            -0.5,-0.5,+1.0,
             0.0,+0.5,+1.0,
    
             0.0, 0.0,+0.5,
             0.0,+0.5,+1.0,
            +0.5,-0.5,+1.0,
    
             0.0, 0.0,+0.5,
            +0.5,-0.5,+1.0,
            -0.5,-0.5,+1.0,
        };
```

You can add/change any type of object. This example holds just single semi transparent bluish tetrahedron. You could also add transform matrices more coefficients for material properties etc ...

2. **Architecture**

the Vertex shader just initialize corner Rays  of the view (start position and direction) which is interpolated so each fragment represents start ray of back ray tracing process.

**Iterative back ray tracing**

So I created a "static" list of rays and init it with the start ray. The Iteration is done in two steps first the back ray tracing:

1. **Loop through all rays** in a list from the first
2. **Find closest intersection** with scene...

store the position, surface normal and material properties into ray `struct`

3. **If intersection found** and not last "recursion" layer add reflect/refract rays to list at the end.

also store their indexes to the processed ray `struct`

Now your rays should hold all the intersection info you need to reconstruct the color. To do that:

1. **loop through all the recursion levels backwards**
2. **for each of the rays matching actual recursion layer**
3. **compute ray color**

so use lighting equations you want. If the ray contains children add their color to the result based on material properties (reflective and refractive coefficients ...)

Now the first ray should contain the color you want to output.

**Uniforms used:**

`tm_eye`view camera matrix

 `aspect`view ys/xs aspect ratio

 `n0` empty space refraction index (unused yet)

 `focal_length` camera focal length

 `fac_siz` resolution of the scene square texture

 `fac_num` number of floats actually used in the scene texture

 `fac_txr` texture unit for the scene texture

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

The fragment shader contains my debug prints so you will need also the texture if used see the QA:

- [GLSL debug prints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214)

**ToDo:**

add matrices for objects, camera etc.

 add material properties (shininess, reflection/refraction coefficient)

 **Snell's law** right now the direction of new rays are wrong ...

 may be separate **R,G,B** to 3 start rays and combine at the end

 fake **SSS** Subsurface scattering based on ray lengths

 better implement lights (right now they are constants in a code)

 implement more primitives (right now only triangles are supported)

**[Edit1] code debug and upgrade**

I removed old source code to fit inside 30KB limit. If you need it then dig it from edit history. Had some time for more advanced debugging for this and here the result:

[image: preview]

this version got resolved some geometrical,accuracy,domain problems and bugs. I got implemented both reflections and refractions as is shown on this debug draw for test ray:

[image: debug view]

In the debug view only the cube is transparent and last ray that does not hit anything is ignored. So as you can see the ray split ... The ray ended inside cube due to total reflection angle And I disable all reflections inside objects for speed reasons.

The 32bit `floats` for intersection detection are a bit noisy with distances so you can use 64bit `doubles` instead but the speed drops considerably in such case. Another option is to rewrite the equation to use relative coordinates which are more precise in this case of use.

Here the `float` shaders source:

**Vertex:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
uniform float aspect;
uniform float focal_length;
uniform mat4x4 tm_eye;
layout(location=0) in vec2 pos;

out smooth vec2 txt_pos;    // frag position on screen <-1,+1> for debug prints
out smooth vec3 ray_pos;    // ray start position
out smooth vec3 ray_dir;    // ray start direction
//------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    vec4 p;
    txt_pos=pos;
    // perspective projection
    p=tm_eye*vec4(pos.x/aspect,pos.y,0.0,1.0);
    ray_pos=p.xyz;
    p-=tm_eye*vec4(0.0,0.0,-focal_length,1.0);
    ray_dir=normalize(p.xyz);

    gl_Position=vec4(pos,0.0,1.0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Fragment:**

```cpp
//------------------------------------------------------------------
#version 420 core
//------------------------------------------------------------------
// Ray tracer ver: 1.000
//------------------------------------------------------------------
in smooth vec3      ray_pos;    // ray start position
in smooth vec3      ray_dir;    // ray start direction
uniform float       n0;         // refractive index of camera origin
uniform int         fac_siz;    // square texture x,y resolution size
uniform int         fac_num;    // number of valid floats in texture
uniform sampler2D   fac_txr;    // scene mesh data texture
out layout(location=0) vec4 frag_col;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//#define _debug_print
#define _reflect
#define _refract
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef _debug_print
in vec2 txt_pos;                // frag screen position <-1,+1>
uniform sampler2D txr_font;     // ASCII 32x8 characters font texture unit
uniform float txt_fxs,txt_fys;  // font/screen resolution ratio
const int _txtsiz=64;           // text buffer size
int txt[_txtsiz],txtsiz;        // text buffer and its actual size
vec4 txt_col=vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0); // color interface for txt_print()
bool _txt_col=false;            // is txt_col active?
void txt_decimal(vec2 v);       // print vec3 into txt
void txt_decimal(vec3 v);       // print vec3 into txt
void txt_decimal(vec4 v);       // print vec3 into txt
void txt_decimal(float x);      // print float x into txt
void txt_decimal(int x);        // print int x into txt
void txt_print(float x0,float y0);  // print txt at x0,y0 [chars]
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void main(void)
    {
    const vec3  light_dir=normalize(vec3(0.1,0.1,1.0));
    const float light_iamb=0.1;                 // dot offset
    const float light_idir=0.5;                 // directional light amplitude
    const vec3 back_col=vec3(0.2,0.2,0.2);      // background color

    const float _zero=1e-6;     // to avoid intrsection with start point of ray
    const int _fac_triangles=0; // r,g,b, refl,refr,n, type, triangle count, { x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 }
    const int _fac_spheres  =1; // r,g,b, refl,refr,n, type, sphere count,   { x,y,z,r }
    // ray scene intersection
    struct _ray
        {
        vec3 pos,dir,nor;
        vec3 col;
        float refl,refr;// reflection,refraction intensity coeficients
        float n0,n1,l;  // refaction index (start,end) , ray length
        int lvl,i0,i1;  // recursion level, reflect, refract
        };
    const int _lvls=5;
    const int _rays=(1<<_lvls)-1;
    _ray ray[_rays]; int rays;

    vec3 v0,v1,v2,pos;
    vec3 c,col;
    float refr,refl;
    float tt,t,n1,a;
    int i0,ii,num,id;

    // fac texture access
    vec2 st; int i,j; float ds=1.0/float(fac_siz-1);
    #define fac_get texture(fac_txr,st).r; st.s+=ds; i++; j++; if (j==fac_siz) { j=0; st.s=0.0; st.t+=ds; }
    // enque start ray
    ray[0].pos=ray_pos;
    ray[0].dir=normalize(ray_dir);
    ray[0].nor=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    ray[0].refl=0.0;
    ray[0].refr=0.0;
    ray[0].n0=n0;
    ray[0].n1=1.0;
    ray[0].l =0.0;
    ray[0].lvl=0;
    ray[0].i0=-1;
    ray[0].i1=-1;
    rays=1;

    // debug print area
    #ifdef _debug_print
    bool _dbg=false;
    float dbg_x0=45.0;
    float dbg_y0= 1.0;
    float dbg_xs=12.0;
    float dbg_ys=_rays+1.0;

    dbg_xs=40.0;
    dbg_ys=10;

    float x=0.5*(1.0+txt_pos.x)/txt_fxs; x-=dbg_x0;
    float y=0.5*(1.0-txt_pos.y)/txt_fys; y-=dbg_y0;
    // inside bbox?
    if ((x>=0.0)&&(x<=dbg_xs)
      &&(y>=0.0)&&(y<=dbg_ys))
        {
        // prints on
        _dbg=true;
        // preset debug ray
        ray[0].pos=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0)*2.5;
        ray[0].dir=vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0);
        }
    #endif

    // loop all enqued rays
    for (i0=0;i0<rays;i0++)
        {
        // loop through all objects
        // find closest forward intersection between them and ray[i0]
        // strore it to ray[i0].(nor,col)
        // strore it to pos,n1
        t=tt=-1.0; ii=1; ray[i0].l=0.0;
        ray[i0].col=back_col;
        pos=ray[i0].pos; n1=n0;
        for (st=vec2(0.0,0.0),i=j=0;i<fac_num;)
            {
            c.r=fac_get;            // RGBA
            c.g=fac_get;
            c.b=fac_get;
            refl=fac_get;
            refr=fac_get;
            n1=fac_get;             // refraction index
            a=fac_get; id=int(a);   // object type
            a=fac_get; num=int(a);  // face count

            if (id==_fac_triangles)
             for (;num>0;num--)
                {
                v0.x=fac_get; v0.y=fac_get; v0.z=fac_get;
                v1.x=fac_get; v1.y=fac_get; v1.z=fac_get;
                v2.x=fac_get; v2.y=fac_get; v2.z=fac_get;
                vec3 e1,e2,n,p,q,r;
                float t,u,v,det,idet;
                //compute ray triangle intersection
                e1=v1-v0;
                e2=v2-v0;
                // Calculate planes normal vector
                p=cross(ray[i0].dir,e2);
                det=dot(e1,p);
                // Ray is parallel to plane
                if (abs(det)<1e-8) continue;
                idet=1.0/det;
                r=ray[i0].pos-v0;
                u=dot(r,p)*idet;
                if ((u<0.0)||(u>1.0)) continue;
                q=cross(r,e1);
                v=dot(ray[i0].dir,q)*idet;
                if ((v<0.0)||(u+v>1.0)) continue;
                t=dot(e2,q)*idet;
                if ((t>_zero)&&((t<=tt)||(ii!=0)))
                    {
                    ii=0; tt=t;
                    // store color,n ...
                    ray[i0].col=c;
                    ray[i0].refl=refl;
                    ray[i0].refr=refr;
                    // barycentric interpolate position
                    t=1.0-u-v;
                    pos=(v0*t)+(v1*u)+(v2*v);
                    // compute normal (store as dir for now)
                    e1=v1-v0;
                    e2=v2-v1;
                    ray[i0].nor=cross(e1,e2);
                    }
                }

            if (id==_fac_spheres)
             for (;num>0;num--)
                {
                float r;
                v0.x=fac_get; v0.y=fac_get; v0.z=fac_get; r=fac_get;
                // compute l0 length of ray(p0,dp) to intersection with sphere(v0,r)
                // where rr= r^-2
                float aa,bb,cc,dd,l0,l1,rr;
                vec3 p0,dp;
                p0=ray[i0].pos-v0;  // set sphere center to (0,0,0)
                dp=ray[i0].dir;
                rr = 1.0/(r*r);
                aa=2.0*rr*dot(dp,dp);
                bb=2.0*rr*dot(p0,dp);
                cc=    rr*dot(p0,p0)-1.0;
                dd=((bb*bb)-(2.0*aa*cc));
                if (dd<0.0) continue;
                dd=sqrt(dd);
                l0=(-bb+dd)/aa;
                l1=(-bb-dd)/aa;
                if (l0<0.0) l0=l1;
                if (l1<0.0) l1=l0;
                t=min(l0,l1); if (t<=_zero) t=max(l0,l1);
                if ((t>_zero)&&((t<=tt)||(ii!=0)))
                    {
                    ii=0; tt=t;
                    // store color,n ...
                    ray[i0].col=c;
                    ray[i0].refl=refl;
                    ray[i0].refr=refr;
                    // position,normal
                    pos=ray[i0].pos+(ray[i0].dir*t);
                    ray[i0].nor=pos-v0;
                    }
                }
            }
        ray[i0].l=tt;
        ray[i0].nor=normalize(ray[i0].nor);
        // split ray from pos and ray[i0].nor
        if ((ii==0)&&(ray[i0].lvl<_lvls-1))
            {
            t=dot(ray[i0].dir,ray[i0].nor);

            // reflect
            #ifdef _reflect
            if ((ray[i0].refl>_zero)&&(t<_zero))    // do not reflect inside objects
                {
                ray[i0].i0=rays;
                ray[rays]=ray[i0];
                ray[rays].lvl++;
                ray[rays].i0=-1;
                ray[rays].i1=-1;
                ray[rays].pos=pos;
                ray[rays].dir=ray[rays].dir-(2.0*t*ray[rays].nor);
                ray[rays].n0=ray[i0].n0;
                ray[rays].n1=ray[i0].n0;
                rays++;
                }
            #endif

            // refract
            #ifdef _refract
            if (ray[i0].refr>_zero)
                {
                ray[i0].i1=rays;
                ray[rays]=ray[i0];
                ray[rays].lvl++;
                ray[rays].i0=-1;
                ray[rays].i1=-1;
                ray[rays].pos=pos;

                t=dot(ray[i0].dir,ray[i0].nor);
                if (t>0.0)  // exit object
                    {
                    ray[rays].n0=ray[i0].n0;
                    ray[rays].n1=n0;
                    v0=-ray[i0].nor; t=-t;
                    }
                else{       // enter object
                    ray[rays].n0=n1;
                    ray[rays].n1=ray[i0].n0;
                    ray[i0  ].n1=n1;
                    v0=ray[i0].nor;
                    }
                n1=ray[i0].n0/ray[i0].n1;
                tt=1.0-(n1*n1*(1.0-t*t));
                if (tt>=0.0)
                    {
                    ray[rays].dir=(ray[i0].dir*n1)-(v0*((n1*t)+sqrt(tt)));
                    rays++;
                    }
                }
            #endif
            }
        else if (i0>0) // ignore last ray if nothing hit
            {
            ray[i0]=ray[rays-1];
            rays--; i0--;
            }
        }
    // back track ray intersections and compute output color col
    // lvl is sorted ascending so backtrack from end
    for (i0=rays-1;i0>=0;i0--)
        {
        // directional + ambient light
        t=abs(dot(ray[i0].nor,light_dir)*light_idir)+light_iamb;
        t*=1.0-ray[i0].refl-ray[i0].refr;
        ray[i0].col.rgb*=t;
        // reflect
        ii=ray[i0].i0;
        if (ii>=0) ray[i0].col.rgb+=ray[ii].col.rgb*ray[i0].refl;
        // refract
        ii=ray[i0].i1;
        if (ii>=0) ray[i0].col.rgb+=ray[ii].col.rgb*ray[i0].refr;
        }

    col=ray[0].col;

    // debug prints
    #ifdef _debug_print
/*
    if (_dbg)
        {
        txtsiz=0;
        txt_decimal(_lvls);
        txt[txtsiz]=' '; txtsiz++;
        txt_decimal(rays);
        txt[txtsiz]=' '; txtsiz++;
        txt_decimal(_rays);
        txt_print(dbg_x0,dbg_y0);

        for (ii=0;ii<rays;ii++)
            {
            txtsiz=0;
            txt_decimal(ray[ii].lvl);
            txt_print(dbg_x0,dbg_y0+ii+1);
            }

        for (ii=0,st=vec2(0.0,0.0),i=j=0;i<fac_num;ii++)
            {
            c.r=fac_get;            // RGBA
            txtsiz=0;
            txt_decimal(c.r);
            txt_print(dbg_x0,dbg_y0+ii+1);
            }
        if (_txt_col) col=txt_col.rgb;
        }
*/
    if (_dbg)
        {
        float x=dbg_x0,y=dbg_y0;
        vec3 a=vec3(1.0,2.0,3.0);
        vec3 b=vec3(5.0,6.0,7.0);
        txtsiz=0; txt_decimal(dot(a,b)); txt_print(x,y); y++;
        txtsiz=0; txt_decimal(cross(a,b)); txt_print(x,y); y++;
        if (_txt_col) col=txt_col.rgb;
        }
    #endif

    frag_col=vec4(col,1.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifdef _debug_print
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decimal(vec2 v)        // print vec2 into txt
    {
                      txt[txtsiz]='('; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.x); txt[txtsiz]=','; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.y); txt[txtsiz]=')'; txtsiz++;
    txt[txtsiz]=0;  // string terminator
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decimal(vec3 v)        // print vec3 into txt
    {
                      txt[txtsiz]='('; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.x); txt[txtsiz]=','; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.y); txt[txtsiz]=','; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.z); txt[txtsiz]=')'; txtsiz++;
    txt[txtsiz]=0;  // string terminator
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decimal(vec4 v)        // print vec4 into txt
    {
                      txt[txtsiz]='('; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.x); txt[txtsiz]=','; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.y); txt[txtsiz]=','; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.z); txt[txtsiz]=','; txtsiz++;
    txt_decimal(v.w); txt[txtsiz]=')'; txtsiz++;
    txt[txtsiz]=0;  // string terminator
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decimal(float x)       // print float x into txt
    {
    int i,j,c;                  // l is size of string
    float y,a;
    const float base=10;
    // handle sign
    if (x<0.0) { txt[txtsiz]='-'; txtsiz++; x=-x; }
     else      { txt[txtsiz]='+'; txtsiz++; }
    // divide to int(x).fract(y) parts of number
    y=x; x=floor(x); y-=x;
    // handle integer part
    i=txtsiz;                   // start of integer part
    for (;txtsiz<_txtsiz;)
        {
        a=x;
        x=floor(x/base);
        a-=base*x;
        txt[txtsiz]=int(a)+'0'; txtsiz++;
        if (x<=0.0) break;
        }
    j=txtsiz-1;                 // end of integer part
    for (;i<j;i++,j--)          // reverse integer digits
        {
        c=txt[i]; txt[i]=txt[j]; txt[j]=c;
        }
    // handle fractional part
    for (txt[txtsiz]='.',txtsiz++;txtsiz<_txtsiz;)
        {
        y*=base;
        a=floor(y);
        y-=a;
        txt[txtsiz]=int(a)+'0'; txtsiz++;
        if (y<=0.0) break;
        }
    txt[txtsiz]=0;  // string terminator
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_decimal(int x)     // print int x into txt
    {
    int a,i,j,c;            // l is size of string
    const int base=10;
    // handle sign
    if (x<0.0) { txt[txtsiz]='-'; txtsiz++; x=-x; }
     else      { txt[txtsiz]='+'; txtsiz++; }
    // handle integer part
    i=txtsiz;               // start of integer part
    for (;txtsiz<_txtsiz;)
        {
        a=x;
        x/=base;
        a-=base*x;
        txt[txtsiz]=int(a)+'0'; txtsiz++;
        if (x<=0) break;
        }
    j=txtsiz-1;             // end of integer part
    for (;i<j;i++,j--)      // reverse integer digits
        {
        c=txt[i]; txt[i]=txt[j]; txt[j]=c;
        }
    txt[txtsiz]=0;  // string terminator
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void txt_print(float x0,float y0)   // print txt at x0,y0 [chars]
    {
    int i;
    float x,y;
    // fragment position [chars] relative to x0,y0
    x=0.5*(1.0+txt_pos.x)/txt_fxs; x-=x0;
    y=0.5*(1.0-txt_pos.y)/txt_fys; y-=y0;
    // inside bbox?
    if ((x<0.0)||(x>float(txtsiz))||(y<0.0)||(y>1.0)) return;
    // get font texture position for target ASCII
    i=int(x);               // char index in txt
    x-=float(i);
    i=txt[i];
    x+=float(int(i&31));
    y+=float(int(i>>5));
    x/=32.0; y/=8.0;    // offset in char texture
    txt_col=texture(txr_font,vec2(x,y));
    _txt_col=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The code is not optimized yet I wanted to have the physics working correctly first. There are still not Fresnells implemented but `refl,refr` coefficients of material are used instead.

Also you can ignore the debug prints stuff (they are encapsulated by `#define`).

I build a small class for the geometry texture so I can easily set up scene objects. This is how the scene was initiated for the preview:

```cpp
ray.beg();
//                 r   g   b rfl rfr   n
ray.add_material(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_box   ( 0.0, 0.0, 6.0,9.0,9.0,0.1);
ray.add_material(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.1,0.8,_n_glass); ray.add_sphere( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5,0.5);
ray.add_material(1.0,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_sphere( +2.0, 0.0, 2.0,0.5);
ray.add_material(0.1,1.0,0.1,0.3,0.0,_n_glass); ray.add_box   ( -2.0, 0.0, 2.0,0.5,0.5,0.5);
ray.add_material(0.1,0.1,1.0,0.3,0.0,_n_glass);
ray.add_tetrahedron
    (
     0.0, 0.0, 3.0,
    -1.0,-1.0, 4.0,
    +1.0,-1.0, 4.0,
     0.0,+1.0, 4.0
    );
ray.end();
```

It is important so computed normals are facing out of objects because that is used for detecting inside/outside object crossings.

**P.S.**

If you're interested here is my volumetric 3D back ray tracer:

- [How to best write a voxel engine in C with performance in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214)
- [here archive for low rep users](https://web.archive.org/web/20180618064202/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090782/how-to-best-write-a-voxel-engine-in-c-with-performance-in-mind/48092685#48092685)

Here newer version of this "Mesh" Raytracer supporting hemisphere objects:

- [Ray tracing a Hemisphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57149081/2521214)