# OpenGL Interpolation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, opengl, interpolation

I've written my own 3D Game Engine in Java by using OpenGL (LWJGL).
I'd like to write a Raytracer that works on the CPU, not on the GPU because the memory for my GPU is limited and the amount of data that I use might be bigger than the memory available on my graphics card.

I did some ray-triangle intersection stuff and so on but I need to know how to interpolate values in a triangle like OpenGL does.

What I know is the x,y and z coordinate of each vertex.

[image]

What algorithm is usually used in OpenGL for doing Interpolation like I described.

Comment: Why would this be specific to OpenGL?

Comment: I haven't seen other examples where this is used.

Comment: Just take a weighted average of the vertices.

Comment: This wouldn't work because the left blue point in my graphics would also be influenced by value_2

Comment: Really? 0.6 * value_1 + 0.0 * value_2 + 0.4 * value_3 = ...

Comment: how do you get the 0.0? did you take the distance from the line(value_1, value_3) to value_2 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151269/discussion-between-androbin-and-luecx).

Comment: @Luecx see [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) I know you want CPU side ... but look at the fragment where I do the ray triangle intersection. It computes barycentric `u,v` and then interpolate the color from vertex colors which is exactly what you want ...

Comment: but everything can be done on cpu, or not?

Comment: @Luecx yes I got also CPU side SW raytracer but that code I linked was available  directly ... For the SW render I would need to dig into my archives and I am lazy for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowed from [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72528/how-can-i-project-a-3d-point-onto-a-3d-line)

> You simply need to project vector AP onto vector AB, then add the
>   resulting vector to point A.
>
> Here is one way to compute it:
>
> A + dot(AP,AB) / dot(AB,AB) * AB This formula will work in 2D and in
>   3D. In fact it works in all dimensions.

In your case, A = value_1, AB = value_3 - value_1 and AP = value - value_1