# Triangle intersection in raytracer not working

Tags: javascript, geometry, raytracing

I am trying to make my own raytracer in Javascript. So far the spheres work very well. I now want to expand the capabilities to include triangles, and from there I can go to squares, cubes and beyond. The code I have for finding intersections with triangles is as follows

```
function triangleIntersection(t, r) {
var norm = triangleNormal(t);
var dist = triangleDistance(t);
var a = Vector.dotProduct(r.vector, norm);

if (a === 0) {
    return -1;
} else {
    var b = Vector.dotProduct(norm, Vector.add(r.point, Vector.negative(Vector.multiply(norm, dist))));
    var d = -1 * b / a;

    var qx = Vector.scale(r.vector, d).x + r.point.x;
    var qy = Vector.scale(r.vector, d).y + r.point.y;
    var qz = Vector.scale(r.vector, d).z + r.point.z;

    var q = new Vector(qx, qy, qz);

    var ca = Vector.subtract(t.points[2], t.points[0]);
    var qa = Vector.subtract(q, t.points[0]);
    var t1 = Vector.dotProduct(Vector.crossProduct(ca, qa), norm);

    var bc = Vector.subtract(t.points[1], t.points[2]);
    var qc = Vector.subtract(q, t.points[2]);
    var t2 = Vector.dotProduct(Vector.crossProduct(bc, qc), norm);

    var ab = Vector.subtract(t.points[0], t.points[1]);
    var qb = Vector.subtract(q, t.points[1]);
    var t3 = Vector.dotProduct(Vector.crossProduct(ab, qb), norm);

    if ((t1 >= 0) && (t2 >= 0) && (t3 >= 0)) {
        return 1 * b / a;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

}

Triangle objects have a point array (`points[]`) and item 0 is point A, item 1 is point B and item 2 is point C. The parameter `t` is one of these triangles. The parameter `r` is a ray object, with properties `point` which is the origin, and `vector`, which is the direction.

I also have these functions for finding normal and distance of a triangle.

```
function triangleNormal(s) {
var ca = Vector.subtract(s.points[2], s.points[0]);
var ba = Vector.subtract(s.points[1], s.points[0]);
var norm = Vector.unitVector(Vector.crossProduct(ca, ba));

return norm;
}

function triangleDistance(t) {
    return Vector.dotProduct(triangleNormal(t, 0), t.points[0]);
}
```

When I render my scene the triangle I use in my scene is red colored. No matter how far I move my camera back the triangle fills the whole scene red. I do not know why this happens.

Comment: Why not try the *Moller-Trumbore* algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Okay i will try this. Thx so much :)

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Ugh the same error. i guess i will have to start from scratch again...

Comment: you should test the intersection code with some artificial cases, to make sure that it is not the problem. In fact I recommend doing unit tests like this on all stages in the pipeline until you isolate the source of error.

Comment: see [Reflection and refraction impossible without recursive ray tracing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) and look for `//compute ray triangle intersection` comment `v0,v1,v2` are the triangle vertexes and `ray[i].dir,ray[i].pos` is the i-th ray direction and position.

Comment: @Spektre i am completely sure the intersection is not the problem... it must be the ray tracer itself... Hmm can you look at [the raytracer tutorial i am following](https://github.com/tmcw/literate-raytracer) and see if u can implement my code in it,but make it work? I am very stumped..

Comment: @Adam what about the *projection* part of your code? i.e. where it converts a screen coordinate to a ray. That could be where the problem lies.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I checked that, even created a plane with normal 0, 1, 0, and distance -1, then sent a ray originating at 0, 10, 0 with direction 0, -1, 0 and the WinningObjectIndex (index of the collision in an array of all collisions) is still zero. I can send you my source code if you want it :)

Comment: @Adam yeah at this stage there's really no way for us to help you other than to look at your code. Post it on pastebin if you could

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I worked on a new version. see if you can help with this, it doesnt work either... why am i so bad at making stuff.. lol but see if you can find any errors, this doesnt detect any collisions. u can use console.log(wobj); at line 173 to c what i mean. Heres the link https://pastebin.com/7864idGh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important error in your plane intersection code is this comparison operation:

`a === 0`

There are two things wrong with it:

1. For ray tracing you want the ray to hit planes *in front* of its source, not behind it, so you need `a < 0`.
2. Even if you *did* want the ray to hit planes behind it, you must *never* do equality operations between floating point values, because floating point calculations are *not exact*. (You must do something like `abs(a) < 1e-6f` or some small value)

Comment: Very useful information. will try and accept if works. :) Thank you sir