# Is there any way to change background color in GLSL according to the 2-D data that I have plotted

Tags: python-3.x, glsl

I want to change the background of my 2-D plot in such a manner that it's intensity increases or decreases according to the data. The programme that I have written below works in such a way that it changes the colour of line but I want same thing happen to my background.

This is the result that I am getting from code below:

[image: img]

```cpp
VS = """
#version 450
// Attribute variable that contains coordinates of the vertices.
layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
out vec2 p;
uniform float count;

// Main function, which needs to set `gl_Position`.
in vec3 vertex_position;
void main() {
  p = position;

  gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0., 1.);
}
"""
FS = """
#version 450
// Output variable of the fragment shader, which is a 4D vector containing the
// RGBA components of the pixel color.
in vec2 p;
out vec4 out_color;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;


// Main fragment shader function.

void main()
{
    // We simply set the pixel color to yellow.
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;

    vec3 color = vec3(p.y);

    float pct = smoothstep( p.y-0.9, p.y, st.y) -
          smoothstep( p.y, p.y+0.9, st.y);

    color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    out_color = vec4(color,1.0);


}


"""
```

And this is the result that I desire:

[image: img]

Comment: any sample input? where you're stuck (what exactly is preventing you from solving this)? you post just foreign shaders code  but we now nothing about how you pass the data,  how and what your code does without disecting it so most of us will just pass ... If you want change background than you need to render QUAD covering screen instead of polyline .... and have access to polyline for each fragment ... or use multipass filtering on the rendered polyline to create background by bleeding colors ...

Comment: @Spektre input is of 2-D numpy array where it constitutes coordinates of X and Y axis something like this ([[-1, -0.5], [-0.5, 0], [-0.2, 0.3]….]). I am very new to this so can you please pass any tutorial related to multipass filtering. Also can you please give some light on how to pass data in another QUAD shader??

Comment: I do not code in Python. But usual way is to pack your polyline coordinates into texture (using texture as a array of coordinates instead of array of colors ...) Here an example [raytrace through 3D mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) it renders single quad covering screen and shaders do the rest. Geometry is passed as texture instead of using `glVertex` or `VBO/VAO` From there you just in fragment compute the distance to polyline and compute color from it ...

Comment: Thanks for this approach . I'll definitely try it. Can you also give me some insight on as how to approach for multiple lines (as I have displayed in second image above in Question)?

Comment: the same you just specify a formatted polyline so either first number is number of points or you define a specific number (safely distinct from the coordinates used to be end of polyline and two consequent such numbers mean end of geometry ... Problem with this approach is that each fragment need to process whole geometry which might get slow for bigger data ... to remedy you can use spatial sorting/topology like QUAD Tree