# Trouble getting a raytracer camera representation for different aspect ratios

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I am trying to make my camera representation work for images whose aspect ratio isn't 1 (640x480, 1920x1080...), but I am having some trouble getting it to work.

The camera model is pretty simple, as it's a pinhole camera with `(F)orward`, `(L)eft` and `(U)p` vectors, and a point in space which serves as its `(O)rigin`. `F` points towards the center of the image plane, and `U` and `L` are perpendicular with each other and with `F`, forming the camera's coordinate space.

The way it works is that I define everything except the `L` vector, which is the normalized cross product of `F` and `U` multiplied by the aspect ratio, so that its length is "as wide" as the image is going to be compared to its height.

Then, to get a ray pointing at `(i, j)`, I just create a ray starting at `O` and pointing at the top-left corner (`U + F + L`)

The code is this:

```
class Camera {
public:
    Direction L, U, F;
    Point O;
    size_t width, height;
    size_t rays_per_pixel;

private:
    // For randomizing ray's directions inside the pixel's square
    static std::mt19937 gen;
    static std::uniform_real_distribution<double> pixel_distr;

public:

    Camera(Point _O, Direction _U, Direction _F, size_t _width, size_t _height, size_t _rays_per_pixel) :
            U(_U),
            F(_F),
            O(_O),
            width(_width),
            height(_height),
            rays_per_pixel(_rays_per_pixel) {
        // L perpendicular to F and U, then multiplied with the aspect ratio

        double aspect_ratio = ((double) _width / (double) _height);
        // * between vectors is cross product, 
        // .v just addresses their internal vector class
        L = (F.v * U.v).normalize() * aspect_ratio;
    }


    // Return a ray pointing from O to a pixel in the image, with a small 
    // random variation across the pixel's area
    [[nodiscard]] Ray get_ray(size_t _i, size_t _j) const {
        // Puts the ray in the pixel's center, then adds to it a random value between [0, 0.5)
        double i = (double) _i + 0.5 + pixel_distr(gen);
        double j = (double) _j + 0.5 + pixel_distr(gen);

        return {
            O, // Origin

            Direction((U.v + F.v + L.v                      // Top left corner
                    - ((2*L.v.modulus()*L.v)/((double) width) * j)        // Right advance (as a substraction)
                    - ((2*U.v.modulus()*U.v)/((double) height) * i)))     // Downwards advance (as a substraction)
        }; //
    }
```

If I indicate `width` and `height` with an aspect ratio of `1`, I get this, with 512x512 as an example (ignore the texture, I know)
[image: non borked]:

If I indicate `width` and `height` with an aspect ratio of `2` or whatever else, like 640x480 I get this, which at least is somewhat hilarious:

[image: borked]

The vectors used are:

`Point O(0, 0, -3.5);`

`Direction U(0, 1, 0);`

`Direction F(0, 0, 3);`

And `L` in the first case is Direction `L(-1, 0, 0)` whereas in the second case is `L(-2, 0, 0)`.

It seems to repeat the image vertically with a pattern, and I made sure the logic error shouldn't be outside of this (I ask for every single pixel across the plane correctly, etc.)

Is something else needed to get a "widescreen" image? Should I change the camera model?

Comment: the output looks more like pixelformat mismatch than aspect ratio problem ... take a look at [GLSL 3D Mesh back raytracer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45140313/2521214) for some inspiration on how I deal with camera there (vertex shader)

Comment: just an idea if after change from 1:1 aspect to 2:1 you got 2 images ... then you most likely multiplied instead of divide the x axis ray spread by aspect (or viceversa)

Comment: @Spektre Hi, thanks! I actually noticed there was a computer graphics community so I posted it there and forgot about here. It was actually really dumb: I was indexing the flattened matrix for the image as `i*height + j` instead of `i*width + j`...thank you nonetheless :)